# show remaining seconds every day PHP

Tags: php, time, diff

I am trying to create a script showing the missing seconds for 10am on 'CEST' time. The problem is when it is for example 10:01, negative seconds are displayed. I clarify that it is for each day, regardless of date. I hope you can help me

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
$inicio = new DateTime('10:00:00');
$HoraActual = date("H:i:s");
$hr = new DateTime($HoraActual);
$tiempo = $inicio->diff($hr);

$diff = $inicio->getTimestamp() - $hr->getTimestamp();
print $diff

?>
```

Comment: The issue is `$HoraActual = date("H:i:s");` It is using the *current time.*  Debugging: `var_dump($inicio, $HoraActual,  $inicio->getTimestamp(),  $hr->getTimestamp(), $diff);`

Comment: but to calculate the seconds remaining from this moment it is necessary to assign the current time, correct?

Comment: I suggest that you debug the code by using 'var_dump' to understand what 'dates and times' are being used in each step. Until you do this, I suspect  that you are working with assumptions that do not match what the code is doing. It will only take a few minutes to do this and you will find the fault quite easily.